# Controlling multiple rgb led strips in different zones with remote simultaneously

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I want to be able to control two rgb led strips with one remote simultaneously as in if I change the color on one strip the other one will match it without requiring another button press. Sync is not required but preferred.

One strip will be around 13 meters long and the second one about 5 meters. They will be about 6 meters apart. Unfortunately they cannot be both connected to one controller.

I have been searching for answers but I ended up with more questions.

If I get two exact controllers and sync one remote to both of them, providing that they are both within range will one button press trigger both of the controllers?

Do controllers that speak to each other exist? As is a master controller that when activated will repeat the signal to a slave controller.

I have been seeing controller products that support multiple zones. I am sure how these would work. Do all the strips need to be connected to the one controller or can you add additional controllers? And are the zones controlled separately or simultaneously?

Comment: are these addressable LEDs, or is every LED on the strip the same color at the same time?

Comment: non addressable, same color at any given time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this [product](http://www.ltechonline.com/html/en/LED-Controller/Easy-RF-System-Series/Wireless-Receiver/T4-CV.html). Multiple independent controllers can be controlled simultaneously with one remote control.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an **amplifier**.   It works like a controller, slaves off another controller.   You send the power output of the controller *as a signal* to the amplifier.  The wires can be quite thin since they take no appreciable current.

Trying to sync using wireless remotes is hopeless.  Controllers don't always get the signal even when you are aiming directly at them.  Two distant controllers, no chance they'll stay in sync.

Comment: does the amplifier need to be wired to the controller? as this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, there needs to be a hardwired connection.